# Google Street View Image API parameter "location"

Tags: api, google-maps, google-street-view

In the Google Street View Image API i can set a parameter that is called "location". In the api is a description that says "...The Street View Image API will snap to the panorama photographed closest to this location..."

Well my question is if there is a way to get other locations to the given lon&lat? Sometimes if i get a picture to a lon&lat there is a building and a big bus stands in front of it and one step previously you can see the hole building. Maybe someone knows the "steps (lon&lat +,- X" between the photography or a way to get a range of picture for a given lon&lat

the problem in pictures:

[good "place"](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=640x480&location=52.516267,13.37684&fov=90&heading=90&pitch=0&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDHtytMakMRpzN82i3TsxA4INU29ousZjA)

[bad "place"](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=640x480&location=52.516462,13.377044&fov=90&heading=130&pitch=0&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDHtytMakMRpzN82i3TsxA4INU29ousZjA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [google.maps.StreetViewPanaorama.getLinks()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPanorama) method that returns the adjacent StreetView locations.